# React State holds the value of my data but map does not display them

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I got stuck rendering a simple list of data.

I am trying to fetch my data and they are logged in the console of the front-end but are not rendered on screen. I have tried to refactor the code adding a key and using a callback function without success. Also, I noticed in the console that my data is stored in two different arrays[screenshot of the state in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMicB.png).

Reading on [Reactjsbeta](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/rendering-lists) it seems I am not doing wrong with the map method syntax.
Here is my code:

```
export default function ListActivities(){
    const [activities, setActivities] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        getAllActivities()
            .then(activities => {
                setActivities(activities)
            })
    }, [])
    return(
        <div className="container mx-auto w-2/3 grid gap-2">
            <div className="overflow-x-auto">
                <table className="table table-compact w-full">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Level</th>
                            <th>Duration</th>
                            <th>Select</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {activities.map(activity => 
                            <tr key={activity.id}>
                                <td>{activity.id}</td>
                                <td>{activity.name}</td>
                                <td>{activity.level}</td>
                                <td>{activity.duration}</td>
                                <td> 
                                <button className="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-xs">Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

where getAllActivities() is a separate JS file imported in the ListActivities.jsx:

```
import { API_URL } from "./api.js";

export async function getAllActivities(){
    // GET from the API all activities
    const response = await fetch(
        API_URL + "/activities/all", 
        {
            method: "GET",
        }
    )
    const getActivitiesResponse = await response.json()
    
    return getActivitiesResponse.activities
}
```

where const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'

Thanks in advance to anybody will take the time to respond

Comment: maybe you should write like this `... activities[0].map(activity => ...`

Comment: It worked at first.. but as soon as the page is refreshed activities[0] results undefined!